# jQuery Money Meter

Tags: jquery, time, counter, currency

I need to create a counter that starts at $0.00 and ends at $5,000.00 over the course of 22 days. I want the value to rise live, so that when a visitor is looking at the counter, it is rising (however slowly).

I'm not sure what the best way to do this is. Any suggestions?

Comment: So what did you already try to do?

Comment: I haven't tried to do anything yet. I'm hoping for some pointers first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just divide the total by the amount of time and update it every few hundred milliseconds: http://jsfiddle.net/qjMWa/10/

Answer (score 1):

There are 1,900,800 seconds in 22 days.  (22 x 24 x 60 x 60).

Dividing 1,900,800 into 500,000 yields a penny increase every 4 seconds (approximately).

So, add a penny to the amount display every 3.8016 seconds.

Comment: But I don't want the counter to start over every time someone loads the page. How might I do this based on current date/time?

Comment: @HWD: See Blender's answer.  You'd save the start date and time somewhere, and the JavaScript would retrieve the start date and time.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need something to track the progress, aka a progress bar. This should be a good starting place: [How do you animate the value for a jQuery UI progressbar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5047498/how-do-you-animate-the-value-for-a-jquery-ui-progressbar)