# Update jQueryUI progress bar with inner.html.data

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have the basic jQueryUI progress bar code here;

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        $("#progressbar").progressbar({
            value: 50,
        });
    });
</script>
```

And then I have a script page which deals with the current upload progress and feeds it back like so;

```
document.getElementById('progressbar').innerHTML = iPercentComplete.toString();
```

That then updates the inner.html of this;

```
<div id="progressbar">&nbsp;</div>
```

What I need is for the progress bar to move in line with the value being updated in the progress bar div. Is this possible? If so how? I can also add code to the script.js page if need be.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$( "#progressbar" ).progressbar( "value" , iPercentComplete.toString() );
```

For Animation see:
[How do you animate the value for a jQuery UI progressbar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5047498/how-do-you-animate-the-value-for-a-jquery-ui-progressbar)

Comment: Tried it, the progressbar div changes to the % amount, but nothing moves on the actual bar, just stays white

Answer (score 1):

```
document.getElementById('progressbar').innerHTML = iPercentComplete.toString();
$( "#progressbar" ).progressbar({value: iPercentComplete});
```

Comment: Tried it, the progressbar div changes to the % amount, but nothing moves on the actual bar, just stays white.

Comment: Is there anyway i could return the data from the script.js file, where its calculated, straight into the jquery

Comment: I guess there's a way, but without seeing the code it's hard to answer

Comment: What about using your first method, but having the bar animate, so its smoothly goes up with the value thats received.