# Animate JQueryUI ProgressBar Value Change

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, progress

I have a jqueryui progress bar and I am updating it's value using some ajax. But, its a little jerky due to the differences in the value changes. Is there a way to animate the change so it slides from value A to value B rather than jumping from value A to Value B?

Comment: Have a look: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5047498/how-do-you-animate-the-value-for-a-jquery-ui-progressbar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if there's an inbuilt way to do this (never touched jquery-ui) but if there isn't any, i would suggest this way:

```
(pseudocode)
When you get a new value...

setTimeout(function() {
    my_plugin.value += 1;
    val--;

    if(val < 1) my_plugin.value = val; // in case val is float.
    else setTimeout(arguments.callee, delay);
}, delay);
```

where val = the value you received from the ajax request.