# I need to pause my progress bar for a couple of seconds before it goes back to null

Tags: c#, multithreading, backgroundworker

I need to pause my progress bar for a couple of seconds before it goes back to null.

I am using Background worker.

The completion in the progress bar is not noticeable, i want to give the user time to notice the job done.

I don't want to use "Thread.sleep" cause it will make my program slow. I think that freezing the ui might help as all my work is done in background thread, but i have no idea how to do that.

Comment: Just leave the progress bar at 100%, display a message box that says "operation completed," and zero the progress bar when the user clicks OK on the message box.

Comment: Do not freeze the UI, your users will hate you.

Comment: Why do you think Thread.Sleep will make your program slow? After all, you want to wait for some (milli)seconds and Thread.Sleep does this very well.

Comment: You could set a timer to dispatch a second later that would clear out the progress bar. This way you don't have any blocking, and don't require user interaction

Comment: @Markus: It also hangs up the UI thread very well too.

Comment: @Brian: not if you do it in the BackgroundWorker.

Comment: @Markus: True, but then it would also delay the `RunWorkerCompleted` event. I believe the OP wanted to delay the resetting of the `ProgressBar` for one 1 second, not delay the actual completion of the work. No?

Comment: @Brian: I totally agree with you that Thread.Sleep is not the perfect solution for the problem as I'd also suggest not to block the UI thread. I just wondered about why Thread.Sleep makes the program slow. Maybe just a misunderstanding on my side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have eventually solved the problem. Though  I didn't actually freeze the UI nor did i use thread.sleep. 
I went into the last sub-function and reported the progress as 100 there. So when it completes the function the progress bar also reaches 100.but it takes a couple of milliseconds to come back to dowork function and then to runworkercompleted. It gives a window for the user to notice it complete. Thanks everyone!

I appreciate all your efforts and advices.

Answer (score 2):

This is a perfect scenario for using the new `async` and `await` keywords.

```
private async void YourBackgroundWorker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
  YourProgressBar.Value = 100;
  await Task.Delay(100);
  YourProgressBar.Value = 0;
}
```

Comment: I did try it but it didn't work for me.Thanks anyways

Comment: await and async weren't recognized. And when I found the solution, I didn't bother to try getting them to work.

Comment: @Avi: Okay, yeah, I should have mentioned that those keywords are new and only available in C# 5.0+.

Answer (score 0):

I agree that doing Thread.Sleep seems wrong to solve this issue.  The problem isn't with your calculation, it's a presentation issue.  Perhaps using some sort of animation to cover this would solve your problem.  Not sure what you're using, but check out this thread to see jquery progress animation:

[How do you animate the value for a jQuery UI progressbar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5047498/how-do-you-animate-the-value-for-a-jquery-ui-progressbar)

Comment: I think you've made an assumption that the OP is using a web solution.  It has not been stated directly, but the tags suggest its straight c#.