# Animating jQuery progress bar

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I've found this nice animating progress bar tutorial:

http://www.cssflow.com/snippets/animated-progress-bar/demo

However the progress bar doesn't use jquery and the tutorial doesn't tell you how to link multiple buttons to the progressbar. So after searching I found this tutorial:

http://www.jcode.ninja/id/8561710

I've simply used the code in the tutorial above for now just to see if i can get it working.

My question is how do you animate the progress in the same way as the first tutorial? Is it possible to apply a gradient starting with green then fading to orange then fading into red. I can do this in photoshop, which isnt a problem but can you add it as a progressbar "skin" rather than the default grey?

Thanks in advance

Comment: u need to animate bar slowly right

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply. Sorry, I don't think my original question was clear enough. How do you tell the progressbar to start animating using jQuery?

Answer (score 1):

I used the first tutorial and created a JSfiddle of that:
https://jsfiddle.net/LgfcwxLu/

What you should do is add to the .progress css the gradient:

```
.progress {
   padding: 4px;
   background: #5fff32; /* Old browsers */
   background: -moz-linear-gradient(left,  #5fff32 0%, #ff9730 50%, #ff0000 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
   background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, color-stop(0%,#5fff32), color-stop(50%,#ff9730), color-stop(100%,#ff0000)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
   background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left,  #5fff32 0%,#ff9730 50%,#ff0000 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
   background: -o-linear-gradient(left,  #5fff32 0%,#ff9730 50%,#ff0000 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
   background: -ms-linear-gradient(left,  #5fff32 0%,#ff9730 50%,#ff0000 100%); /* IE10+ */
   background: linear-gradient(to right,  #5fff32 0%,#ff9730 50%,#ff0000 100%); /* W3C */
   filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#5fff32', endColorstr='#ff0000',GradientType=1 ); /* IE6-9 */
 }
```

You can create the gradient with this tool:
http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/

Let me know if that helps you?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. The site I'm working on needs to work with IE8. Would css3 be compatable? If not would a .png be ok to use if set as background instead?

Comment: If you look at my css code, you can see that the last line of the code:        
    
**filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#5fff32', endColorstr='#ff0000',GradientType=1 ); /* IE6-9 */** 
says that this should also work in IE8. If that is not the case, you could  use an image as the background

Answer (score 0):

You could use css3 transitions and changing background color. You set the transition and then, by just changing the background color, the animation performs. Check this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/en2cb2vq/

CSS Code:

```
.square {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
  transition: background-color 0.5s ease;
  background-color: red;
}
.square.green {
  background-color: green;
}
```

HTML Code:

```
<a href="#">click me</a>
<div class="square"></div>
```

Javascript (with jQuery):

```
$("a").click( function() {
 $(".square").addClass("green"); 
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

this will be duplicate question already asked question, try to search and achieve it, don't ask question like this, if having error in code means u can post the issue,
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5047498/how-do-you-animate-the-value-for-a-jquery-ui-progressbar](http://progress%20bar%20animate)

Answer (score 0):

You can animate the bar using CSS `Transition` of `.ui-progressbar-value`.

```
.ui-progressbar-value{
    -webkit-transition: all 1s; /* Safari */
    transition: all 1s;
}
```

Take care: `Transition` isn't Cross Browser.
References: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_transitions.asp

#### A WORKING EXAMPLE:

http://jsfiddle.net/y2mg8ejk/

#### IE8/9 fallbacks

with old Browser you can use and other approch. jQuery UI has `color animation` inside his surce code:

I change my Fiddle to use jquery instead transition:

Take a look: http://jsfiddle.net/y2mg8ejk/2/

jQuery UI - Color Animation **[doc]**: http://jqueryui.com/animate/

You can use this with old browser and the `transition` with other.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for this are there any jquery commands I could use to animate the progressbar instead of transitions? My project needs to support IE 8

Comment: Hi Again, just wondering whether you example above can be done using jquery animations?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply apply the styles from the colored progress-bar onto the jQuery UI progress-bar, including the stripes. In the following jsfiddle I took the essential css and changed the `.progress-bar` class name in the stylesheet to `.ui-progressbar-value`. To change the color, just change it with jQuery inline or add classes for each color and switch the class with jQuery.

[See the fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5r7vbfht/2/). It is not perfect but it will give you an idea.